# Spring Security show home page only after succes login

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I would like to show user home page only after succes login.

I mean, when somebody will hit the url for application like "ht'tp://localhost:8081/example", I want to redirect him to "ht'tp://localhost:8081/example/login" and only after loging in, user will see default home page which will be on "url/example" where he can do some actions or logout.

Using example from mkyong http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/.

Didn't find answer on stack, maybe someone will help me with this.

Comment: Could you explain the problem you are having while implementing this?

Comment: Don't have problem with implement this, but I want after deploy aplication, when im hiting localhost:8081/example redirect to login page.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `.defaultSuccessUrl("url/example", true)` to the `HttpSecurity` object in the security config. This should lead to the user always being redirected to the given page after a successful login.